# Android use backstack with fragments

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, back-stack

Today I got another problem using android.

First of all i have an app which has a login activity. so when my credentials are correct, i start a new activity using an intent. so now you see a tabbar. when i call my onTabSelected() method i remove the current fragment and show for example a gridview. if i tap an element in this gridview the fragment is replaced and my app dives deeper into another fragment (an expandable list with another details fragment).

So my problem is if I tap the back button now, the app returns to my very first activity (the login activity) and not to the last fragment which should be the grid view.

```
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment frag = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    FragmentTransaction tr = fm.beginTransaction();


    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
    case 1: {//Produkte
        ProdukteGrid pg = new ProdukteGrid();           

        if(frag != null)
            tr.remove(frag);

        tr.add(R.id.container, pg,pg.getTAG());
        tr.addToBackStack(pg.getTAG());
    }
```

...
my grid:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.produkte_gridmain, container, false);

    mGV = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    mGV.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), CATEGORY));

    mGV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            Fragment frag = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
            FragmentTransaction tr = fm.beginTransaction();
            switch (position) {
            case 0: {
                // startActivity(new Intent(MyGrid.this,
                // MainActivity.class));
                ProdukteList f = new ProdukteList();

                tr.remove(frag);
                tr.add(R.id.container, f,f.getTAG());
                tr.addToBackStack(f.getTAG());
            }
                break;
            }
            tr.commit();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

My main layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</FrameLayout>
```

I hope you can help me..:)

**EDIT**

for better understanding i added a picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `replace` instead of `remove` and `add` `fragment`

Instead of this :

```
tr.remove(frag);
tr.add(R.id.container, f,f.getTAG());
```

Use this :

```
tr.replace(R.id.container, f,f.getTAG());
```

And also check if you `override` `onBackPressed` event on your activity. Check code there make sure you are not finishing activity manually.

Comment: this was my first intention. i did this and then i read in several forums it might be better to use remove() and add() despite of replace()

Comment: or just for the last fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of remove and add try replacing a fragment:

```
   fragmentTransaction.replace(..............);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

If it can helps you, usually i do my transitions like this :

```
AlbumGridFragment fragment = new AlbumGridFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.animator.anim_back_right, R.animator.anim_back_left, R.animator.anim_left, R.animator.anim_right)
                .add(R.id.album_fragment, fragment).addToBackStack(MainFragmentActivity.ALBUM_GRID_TAG).commit();
```

and the BackTrack for example :

```
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        int stackSize = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (stackSize == 0) {
            finish();
        }
        else {
            String fragmentTag = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(stackSize - 1).getName();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(fragmentTag, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }
```

Comment: ok, adding fragments should be same as mine. and in which part of the code you do your backtracking? when the back button is pressed?

Comment: Yes i generally do it in onBackPressed() overrided method of the parent activity

Comment: so in this case it would be in the gridview?